# Eigenvalues of operator given polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a homework question that is really bothering me because I cannot manage to use any of the theorems we have studied so far, it seems. Could someone please give me a pointer please (no, Cayley-Hamilton is not the answer) ? I can't quite tie it to the characteristic polynomial, unless I am being stupid; this is over a generic field, not necessarily reals or complex.

Let $p(t) = t^2 + t + 1$, and let it be given that $p(T) = 0$ for an operator $T$. List all the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Cayley-Hamilton, or at least the idea thereof, is the answer: if $p(T)=0$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $p(\lambda)=0$. You can check this "manually" if you like, rather than citing Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but we have no knowledge that p(t) is the characteristic polynomial.

Ah, I see now, but that does not guarantee that a root of p(t) is an eigenvalue only the converse.

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton tells you what happens *if* $p$ is the characteristic polynomial, but even if it is not, $p(T)=0$ still implies $p(\lambda)=0$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. This follows by directly computing $p(T)x$ where $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Thus any eigenvalue must be a root of $p$. The converse question (are all the roots of $p$ eigenvalues of $T$?) is the harder part.

Comment: I believe I can't say any more. We don't know the dimension of the ambient space $V$, so we can't argue from there. $T$ could just be a scalar operator of either root.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant facts are as follows: if $p(t)$ is a polynomial and $T$ an operator such that $p(T) = 0$, then the *minimal* polynomial of $T$ divides $p$.  Moreover, every root of the minimal polynomial of $T$ is necessarily an eigenvalue of $T$.

Note, however, that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is not generally equal to its characteristic polynomial.

To answer this question: the roots of the polynomial $t^2 + t + 1$ are $\omega = -1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$ and $\overline{\omega}$.  If $T$ is a real-linear operator, then both $\omega$ and $\overline{\omega}$ must be eigenvalues of $T$, and $T$ can have no additional eigenvalues.  If, however, $T$ is an arbitrary complex-linear operator, then the eigenvalues of $T$ can be either $\omega, \overline{\omega},$ or both.

Answer (score 0):

As far as p(T)=0, this means that characteristic f(T) pol. divides it: f|p (I mean that p=f*g, g:pol.)  Thus your eigenvalue is one of the roots of p or both of them, as far as g=id.

Comment: Is this not the minimal polynomial rather than the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Well in this case these two are the same but if you had a polynomial of n- grade n=3 and above, the characteristic pol. could be of n grade and less

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following works:

Suppose $Tx=\lambda x$
\begin{align*}
P(T)(x)&=T^2x+Tx+x\\
&=\lambda^2 x+ \lambda x + x\\
&=(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)x=0.
\end{align*}

So the eigenvalues are the solutions to $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$.

Comment: This is the content of the comments: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $p(\lambda)=0$. The real question is about the converse.